# QWizardPage designed in Qt Creater can not set geometry correctly when title is set

Tags: qt, pyqt5, qt-creator, pyuic, qwizardpage

I am trying to design QWizardPage using Qt Creater.

Everything goes fine if I don't set the title of the wizardpage.

However, when I set the title, the wizard I got is strange. **The title takes a large space and the wizard page can not be shown completely**.

What I got in Qt Creator is:

[image]

But what I got using the generated python code is, the widget I added can not be show completely:

[image]

It seems that the size of the wizardpage widget is set to the same as canvas in the Qt Creator, and **doesn't spare some space for the title**. In other words, designing QWizardPage in Qt Creator doesn't take the space that the title occupies in consideration, and got a wrong geometry setting. How can I use Qt Creator to design a QWizardPage.

**The following is how to reproduce my problem:**

I use File->New File or Project, and choose Qt->Qt Designer Form, then in the "choose a form template", I choose QWizardPage. Then after I finish designing in the Qt creater, I convert the ui file to PyQt code by using `pyuic5 wizard.ui -o wizard.py`. I follow this link to [generate python code](https://www.pythonguis.com/tutorials/first-steps-qt-creator/).

The following is my ui file, which is quite simple

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>WizardPage</class>
 <widget class="QWizardPage" name="WizardPage">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>400</width>
    <height>300</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>WizardPage</string>
  </property>
  <property name="title">
   <string>This is the tile</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QGraphicsView" name="graphicsView">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>20</x>
     <y>20</y>
     <width>351</width>
     <height>261</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

My generated python file is:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'qtcchess\wizardpage.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.15.6
#
# WARNING: Any manual changes made to this file will be lost when pyuic5 is
# run again.  Do not edit this file unless you know what you are doing.


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_WizardPage(object):
    def setupUi(self, WizardPage):
        WizardPage.setObjectName("WizardPage")
        WizardPage.resize(400, 300)
        self.graphicsView = QtWidgets.QGraphicsView(WizardPage)
        self.graphicsView.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 20, 351, 261))
        self.graphicsView.setObjectName("graphicsView")

        self.retranslateUi(WizardPage)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(WizardPage)

    def retranslateUi(self, WizardPage):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        WizardPage.setWindowTitle(_translate("WizardPage", "WizardPage"))
        WizardPage.setTitle(_translate("WizardPage", "This is the tile"))
```

And my main file for testing is:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from wizardpage import *
from PyQt5.Qt import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
import sys


class test_wizard_page(QtWidgets.QWizardPage, Ui_WizardPage):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)


class MyWizard(QtWidgets.QWizard):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.test_wizard_page = test_wizard_page(self)
        self.addPage(self.test_wizard_page)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    wizard = MyWizard()
    wizard.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7219323/qwizard-change-height-dimensions-of-title-field

Comment: You must use [layout managers](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html). Right click on an empty area of the wizard page, and select a vertical or horizontal layout from the "Lay out" submenu.

Comment: Thank you! I manged to solve my problem by adding a layout. Would you like to answer this question so that I can accept your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use [layout managers](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html). Right click on an empty area of the wizard page, and select a vertical or horizontal layout from the "Lay out" submenu.